# Excel Formula to return earliest date within "conditional range."

Tags: excel

Not sure if the question is phrase properly, but here's my problem.

I have two columns. One with dates (colum A), and one with values (column B). In the column B, some cells are blank. I want to write a formula that returns the maximum value from the column A, but only for cells in column A with populated column B.

What I have so far is something along the line of:

```
=Max(IF(B3 <> "", ??, ""))
```

Where I have the ??, is it possible to create an array (like one would in VBA) that contains only values in rows where B is blank. Is this the correct approach?

EDIT: I think I have it, how does this sound

```
=MAX(IF(A3:A100 <> "",A3:A100))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use your formula as an array-formula. Enter the formula

```
=MAX(IF(A3:A100<>"",A3:A100))
```

When entering the formula press **CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER**. This converts your formula to an array-formula. You can see that it was successful by looking at the formula which should have `{}` around it now. You can also use this to get the minimum of the dates and also apply other criteria.

Comment: Great. Thanks. If I want to use $ to use absolute ranges, is there anything else I need to consider for array-formulas?

Comment: Absolute ranges shouldn't be a problem. Just make sure that the ranges are of equal length (same number of rows). `=MAX(IF(A3:A5<>"",A3:A6))` would result in an error.

Comment: Ah yes, I wasn't hitting CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing. If the values in the column I'm finding MAX for are derived from a formula, rather than an absolute value, would I need to alter the formula? At the moment, all the values in the date column come from a VLOOKUP formula

Comment: This should not be a problem. Excel will generally calculate all needed cell values to calculate a formula. This includes the formulas inside referenced cells.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. Thanks!